# Using select case and if for differents procedures

Tags: ms-access, vba

I´ve a problem calling a procedure.There are two:

```
Public Sub altaorange()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = "xxxx@orange.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Alta de línea. ATT MR"
    .Body = "Hello MR"
    'Se pueden adjuntar ficheros
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\Mi_Fichero.pdf")
    .Display 'tambien se puede usar .Send y lo situa en la bandeja de salida
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

And:

```
Public Sub bajaorange()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = "xxxx@orange.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Baja de línea . ATT MR"
    .Body =  "Hello MR"
    'Se pueden adjuntar ficheros
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\Mi_Fichero.pdf")
    .Display 'tambien se puede usar .Send y lo situa en la bandeja de salida
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

When I call the first one it works properly, It loads the correct procedure. I show the code:

```
Select Case operador

    Case Is = "ORANGE"

    'Alta de línea ORANGE

        If fam = "XX-YYYY" Or fam = "ZZ-WWWW" Then

            Call altaorange

        End if

     End Select
```

But if i use this:

```
    Case Is = "ORANGE"

        'Baja de línea ORANGE

        If fam = "XX-YYYY" Or fam = "ZZ-WWWW" And baja ="PPPPP" Or baja ="DDDDD" Then

           Call bajaorange

        End If
End Select
```

Loads the first procedure (altaorange).

I don´t know it doesn´t load bajaorange proc.

Comment: Without seeing all of the code in context, I can say that a call to 'bajaorange' should never call 'altaorange'. To try and solve, I suggest that you put a breakpoint in your code to EVERY place that 'altaorange' is called. Maybe you have a reference you don't realize.

Comment: If you have the two Select Case statements at the same time, and the fam variable satisifies the first condition it will call altaorange.  If you only have the second case statement, then I'd say you need to look closely at your condition and probably put a couple brackets round the fam options and also the baja options e.g. `If (fam="XX-YYYY" or fam="ZZ-WWWW") And (baja = "PPPPP" Or baja = "DDDDD") Then` but without seeing the full code it's difficult to tell exactly where you're going wrong...

Comment: Wayne is right, it's impossible that your last code snippet calls `altaorange`. If this is what really happens than you have some critical code somewhere else that you didn't show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select Case` will stop within the first match, both are `Case Is = "ORANGE"`, it will only ever make it into the first one.

As `fam` has the same matches of `XX-YYYY` or `ZZ-WWWW` in both instances, when you drop into the first `operador` match of `"ORANGE"` it then goes on to run `altaorange`.

Consider `baja` being the decisive variable. I have also used the below code snippet to show an example of the importance of bracketing `If ... Or/And ... Then` statements

```
If (operador = "ORANGE") and ((fam = "XX-YYYY") Or (fam = "ZZ-WWWW")) then
    If (baja ="PPPPP") Or (baja ="DDDDD") then
        Call bajaorange
    Else
        Call altaorange
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Hello Gary,

I applied this and i´ve a error because  "baja" field is empty. I used and exception but it doesn´t work. How Could I skip this error?

Comment: @Firefox_mig If this helps you we'd appreciate you marking the question as answered